# comma separated txt file import into sql server using bcp utility

Tags: sql-server, import, bcp

I have a comma separated txt file "R97_07-09.txt" with almost 50 millions of rows and want to import them into sql server using bcp utility from command prompt.
The text file is like below:

[image: text preview]

Before importing the data, I have created a table "Inventory", for this data in sql server with below code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Inventory (Productid float NULL,
                            regionid float NULL,
                            shopcode int NULL,
                            QTY float NULL,
                            olapdate int NULL,
                            Inv float NULL);
```

Then I used the below code in command prompt to import the text file into the table:

```
bcp ETLDB.dbo.Inventory in D:\SCM\R97_07-09.txt -T -b 10000 -e D:\SCM\ERRORS.txt -t ","
```

For each column, bcp prompts for field-specific values and I specify the defaults which it suggests:
[image: suggestions]

However after the completion, the data which imported to the server differs a lot from its originals:
[image: imported file]

I also tried with specifying "-n", "-f" in the command and each option resulted in the wrong data format in the destination table.

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "differs". Do you *really* need floating point values to store ID's?

Comment: @Larnu I mean the values are scientific and for example I am sure that the field "olapdate" is a number between 970701 to 9709030. Besides, the original file which is shown above has float type for ids.

Comment: *"I mean the values are scientific"* That *is* a floating point value; you've defined the data type as a `float` so of course you're going to see a floating point value. if you're data really is floating point values, then `float` is the correct choice, and values of `1.2345E-10` are correct as that is a floating point value. Therefore there are no problems. if you don't want a floating point number, don't use `float` and use a `decimal`/`numeric`.

Comment: @Larnu I was suspicious of the correct data transformation, because the "olapdate" field shows different values. as I mentioned, I am sure that this field contains integers between 970701 and 970930. How about that?

Comment: Your file is a character data file. You would only be asked for prefix lengths if BCP is working with native data. Try adding -c and paste the results of the load after running the command with -c. Otherwise, eliminate the uncertainty of what the command is doing and create a format file and use the -f option instead of -c

Comment: Alternately, try specifying 0 for the prefix length. Prefixes are only going to be invovled with SQL native data type. But since your file is clearly a character file, I would use -c. Need to start there.

Comment: Lastly, I agree with Larnu's concern. Do you REALLY need float? I think you should be using decimal/numeric. Your values seem like they have a known, exact, precise scale and precision. Your product ID is always "9...99.999" always 3 places to the right of the decimal. Your QTY field is always 6 places to the right of the decimal... if so, these are not float fields and should be stored and fixed precision fields.

Comment: And... very last... :).... Do you have access to the datatypes of the system these values came from? If not, and you are not certain of their format, I would load into a table of all varchar(50) fields and then do datatype corrections/setting from there into your final table.

Comment: @jamie The -c parameter worked absolutely fine. Thanks for the helpful comments :)